# Can I use 'false' word in this case?

Tags: grammar, translation

I am translating Russian song to English (it's very hard to save rhymes). And one sentence I am going to translate like below:

> Disappear in the darkness and fly to the light.
>   Be quiet in the silence, demons live in the night.
>   The walls can hear secrets, the walls can see false.

The literature grammar isn't important, only a simple speech. Is it possible to say *false* there to save a rhyme? Or does it sound too weird and I should use *a lie* or *a false* only?
**ADDED**
At first my English is very poor... [There](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rkJeFsLTIxhg7DFCW3mT8AR3jG3PyoR7) is previous strings.

Comment: You can't have "a false", & 'see false' doesn't quite work. 'see lies' looks good in English, against the first half of the line. How about posting the line it has to rhyme with & see if anyone can come up with anything to match?

Comment: @Tetsujin, I have updated my post

Comment: @Tetsujin, I like yo offer about *lies* if no word to replace *false* with similar sounds then *lies* is the best.

Comment: 'Lies' would probably qualify as a "half-rhyme" or similar [I'm not a poetry expert, not sure of the actual terminology]... but,  in other words, it's close enough that no-one would find it odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**the walls can see false** would not be idiomatic spoken English but with "artistic license" you could use it in a poem. Lies themselves cannot be **seen**, not unless they are in print. Then you could say **I know a lie when I see one** but normally it would be **... when I hear one**.   You can see that someone is lying. The walls **detect lies** or **the walls know a lie when they hear one**.

P.S. If you're looking for something close to "false" that rhymes with **night** you could say

> The walls can hear secrets and know when something's not right.

Comment: I'm sure artistic license would allow walls to see lies. "Walls have ears" uses a very similar metaphor.

Comment: But do walls have **(o)~(O)** ?

Comment: @Шаx Working with these comments, what about "Walls have ears, walls have eyes / Hear your secrets, know your lies"

Comment: It seems that British ones do have XD - From Dr.Who https://78.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lr2fb1U10g1qeqvd7.gif

Comment: @Шаx I forgot to add the pronouns "Walls have ears, walls have eyes / They hear your secrets, they know your lies"

Comment: Having once been a fan of a song called "Talking in morse, listening in semaphore" about a breakdown of communication in a relationship, walls having ears is no stretch on my imagination at all ;-) Honestly, I see absolutely nothing wrong with the OP's 3 lines, just using 'lies' at the end. it doesn't need any further meaning change, imo.

Comment: Thank you all very much for help! I will take **lies** then because it suits the best for the rhyme. I liked a joke about Dr. Who =)